# Why is AMChart cylinder serial column not filling in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

So I took a example from amcharts website with the column cylinder.
It works perfectly fine on their website and even the example I download works when I open in chrome.

However when I copy and past the exact code into one of my angular components. The chart draws however the cylinder doesn't fill in.

This is what I expect.
[image]

I looked further into it and it seems if I drill down into the actual elements
The angular module fil : url points to "http://local.test.com/#AmChartsEl-1267"
while the example url looks like

```
file:///C:/Users/guest/Desktop/amcharts_3.20.17.free/samples/columnCylinders.html#AmChartsEl-866
```

I think this is causing the base to not be filled. I don't understand why the cylinder chart has to use url while the regular chart fills with just regular rgb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a `<base>` tag set in your application. The underlying SVG uses a url clip-path to set the fill for the cylinders, and the base tag screws with it.

You'll need to set `AmCharts.baseHref = true;` before your chart code in order to fix visual issues that are caused by the `<base>` tag.

[Documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#baseHref)